# Whether to reject the null hypothesis or not at different significant levels

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If you reject a null hypothesis at the $10\%$ level of significance, then explain which of the following statement is correct:

(a) You certainly would reject $H_0$ at $5\%$.

(b) You are absolutely certain that you would not reject it at $5\%$.

(c) You would definitely reject $H_0$ at $15\%$ significance level.

(d) You do not have enough information to decide whether you should reject at $15\%$ or not.

I think it's **(c)** as $p$-value $< 0.10$ (according to the original claim) so it must be less than $0.15$. In case of the options above (c) I think it's not possible to decide as $p$-value might/might not be smaller than $0.05$ as well. I am not sure if I am reasoning this out right or if there are even better reasons for making definite choices.

Comment: I agree with your logic, $p < 0.1$ certainly implies $p < 0.15.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We reject an $\alpha$-level test when $p\le\alpha$. In your case, $\alpha=0.1$. If you reject, then $p\le 0.1$.

**A** We allow for $p>0.05$, so long as $p\le 0.1$. Perhaps $p=0.07$.

**B** If $p\le 0.1$, it might be the case that $p\le 0.05$. Perhaps $p=0.03$.

**C** If $p\le 0.1$, then certainly $p\le 0.15$.

**D** If $p\le 0.1$, then certainly $p\le 0.15$.

You’re right; **C** must be the answer.

Comment: As a minor aside there really is not scientific based reason to chose any level of significance to reject or not reject at. Individual make their own decisions based on what makes sense to them and others might make a different decision. It is impossible to prove who is right or not (I am not disagreeing with the choice of C at all, just pointing out the artificiality of alpha levels). Why not select .0499 rather than .05.:)

Comment: What I find weird about p-values close to the $\alpha$ threshold, say $\alpha=0.05$, is that we might say that $p=0.049$ is so close to $\alpha$ that we don’t want to reject, but also that $p=0.051$ is so close to $\alpha$ that we ought to reject.

Comment: The whole thing seems artificial to me.:) They were decided long ago in practice, long before there was simulation or computers although I am not sure either would have mattered.